# Writting the equation of a sphere?(2 questions)

Tags: geometry

How can I write the equation of a sphere that is centered at the triple point P$(2,4,-4)$ and passes through the origin.

I think I get the how to write the left hand side of the equation which is.

$(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2+(z+4)^2=$ 
but I am not sure what the radius would be I know origin is (0,0,0) so do I use the distance formula.

My second question is how do I write the equation of a sphere that fits the following. THe line segment that  joins P(0,4,2) TO Q (6,0,2) is a diamter.

So I know I can use midpoint formula to find x,y,and z but how would I find the radius to have the complete formula.

Comment: Just plug in $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ and see what value you get. That's your right hand side then. For the second, the centre is the midpoint of the two given points, so compute the square of the distance from it to either of the two.

Comment: To expand on Daniel's comment: you know that the sphere passes through (0,0,0).  So whatever the distance is from $(2,4,-4)$ to $(0,0,0)$ must be the radius.

Comment: I see so the radius for my first one would be 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be finding radii.  The radii can always be found, at least in cases liked these, *via* the distance formula.  In the first case, since $(0, 0, 0)$ is on the sphere centered at $(2, 4, -4)$, the radius must be $\sqrt{(2 - 0)^2 + (4 - 0)^2 + (-4 - 0)^2} = \sqrt {36} = 6$.  Then the equation this sphere is

$(x - 2)^2 + (y -4)^2 + (z + 4)^2 = 36. \tag{1}$

For the second sphere, the center is $\frac{1}{2}((0, 4, 2) + (6, 0, 2)) = (3, 2, 2)$.  The radius is given by the distance from the center to either endpoint of the diameter, so it is
$\sqrt{3^2 + 2^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt {13}$.  Then the second sphere is given by

$(x - 3)^2 + (y -2)^2 + (z -2)^2 = 13. \tag{2}$

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Since the sphere is centered at $(2, 4, -4)$ and passes through the origin, the distance from the origin to this point must be the radius $a$ of the sphere:

$$a = \sqrt{(2-0)^2 + (4-0)^2 + (-4 - 0)^2} = 6.$$

Then the equation of the sphere is simply:

$$(x-2)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z+4)^2 = a^2 = 36.$$

For the second question, the midpoint is indeed the center of the sphere:  $(3,2,2)$.  The radius is the length from the center to one of the points:  $a = \sqrt{(6-3)^2 + (0-2)^2 + (2-2)^2} = \sqrt{13}$.

Then your equations is straightforward:

$$(x-3)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 13.$$

Answer (score 1):

You say that for the right value of $a$, the equation of the sphere is
$$(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2+(z+4)^2= a.$$
You also say that $(0,0,0)$ is a point on the sphere. This means that $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ must satisfy the equation, that is
$$(0-2)^2+(0-4)^2+(0+4)^2= a.$$
There's your $a$!